# Why the kernel have the following property?

Tags: real-analysis

In the chapter X. of book *THEORY OF FUNCTIONS OF A REAL VARIABLE* of natanson, the definition of kernel is given.

> A kernel is a function $\Phi_n(t,x)$ defined in the square $(a\leq t \leq b, a<x<b)$ and such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\alpha^\beta \Phi_n(t,x)dt=1$$ provided $a\leq\alpha<x<\beta\leq b$. It is self-evident that $\Phi_n(t,x)$ is assumed summable with respect to $t$ for every fixed $x$.

Then in the proof of theorem2 (P. I. Romanovsky)

> Suppose the kernel $\Phi_n(t,x)$ is positive and possesses the following property: for fixed n and x, the kernel $\Phi_n(t,x)$, as a function of t only, increases on the closed interval $[a,x]$ and decreases on the closed interval $[x,b]$. Then, for an arbitrary summable function $f(t)$ which is the derivative of its indefinite integral at the point $x$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f(t)\Phi_n(t,x)dt=f(x)$$

It says for every $c\quad(x+\delta\leq c\leq b)$,$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_{x+\delta}^c \Phi_n(t,x)dt=0$ because $\Phi_n(t,x)$ is a kernel, where $\delta$ is found to satisfy $\left| \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}(f(t)-f(x))dt\right|<\epsilon  $ for $0<h\leq\delta$

Why the author gives the assertion?
If $\Phi_n(t,x)=1$ for $(0\leq t\leq 1,0<x<1)$, it is impossible that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_{x+\delta}^c \Phi_n(t,x)dt=0$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\alpha^\beta\Phi_n(t,x)dt=1, \\
& \text{for any} \quad\alpha,\beta\quad \text{s.t.} \quad a\leq\alpha<x<\beta\leq b\end{align}$$
So, let $\alpha=a$
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^\beta\Phi_n(t,x)dt=1\\
&\text{for any}\quad\beta\quad\text{s.t.} \quad x<\beta\leq b\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\beta^b\Phi_n(t,x)dt=0\\
&\text{for any}\quad\beta\quad\text{s.t.} \quad x<\beta\leq b\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The $\Phi_n$ you mention has $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\alpha^\beta\Phi_n(t,x)\,dt=\beta-\alpha\ne1,$$so it is not a kernel.

Comment: Does the definition mean that the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, the words "provided that" means the limit holds for any $\alpha,\beta,x$ with $0\le\alpha<x<\beta\le 1$.

Comment: But if we let $\alpha=x+\delta$ and $\beta=c$, isn't the integral $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{x+\delta}^c \Phi_n(t,x)dt=1$. Why it is $0$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make any sense of that. It's a fact that $\int_\alpha^\beta 1=\beta-\alpha$; that does not tend to $1$ except by coincidence. You question about why it's zero really puzzles me - who said it was zero?